# On Windows, are memory mapped files surrendered when other applications request physical memory?

Tags: windows, mongodb, memory, memory-management

We are using MongoDB as our database for our application and it uses memory mapped files to provide fast access to data files to improve query performance - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use

We have configured it to only use up to 1GB of physical memory for its 'internal cache', it honours this and restricts its working set to around 1GB with a little overhead. Despite this configuration, the memory shows as being full and using the [RAM Map tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) we identified the remaining memory was taken up by a 'memory mapped file'; it behaving as designed:

> Via the filesystem cache, MongoDB automatically uses all free memory that is not used by the WiredTiger cache or by other processes.

So with this in mind, will other applications requesting memory for their 'working set' get greater precedence over the memory allocated to map a file on disk?

We are having issues where other applications on the server are not able to get access to memory in a timely enough fashion causing problems.